# How to look for keywords in Pandas data frame column and assign a tag via dummy variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining

I had no idea how to title this sorry. Basically, I have a CSV file with keywords and tags. It looks like this:

```
col Keyword   Tag

0   Keyword1  Tag1 
1   Keyword2  Tag1 
2   Keyword3  Tag2 
3   Keyword4  Tag2
4   Keyword5  Tag3 
5   Keyword6  Tag3
```

I have a separate data frame that has these columns:

```
col Name  Description  Tag 1  Tag 2  Tag 3 
0   A     ..Keyword1..
1   B     ..Keyword4..
2   C     ..Keyword5..
3   D     ..Keyword4..
4   E     ..Keyword2..
...
```

I want to iterate through each row of my data frame, and check the description to see if it contains any of the keywords in the CSV file. If it does, I want to set the appropriate "tag" column equal to 1, otherwise 0, like so:

```
col Name  Description  Tag 1  Tag 2  Tag 3 
0   A     ..Keyword1..  1      0      0
1   B     ..Keyword4..  0      1      0
2   C     ..Keyword5..  0      0      1
3   D     ..Keyword4..  0      1      0
4   E     ..Keyword2..  1      0      0
...
```

This is how I created the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataframe_file.csv')
keys = pd.read_csv('keyword_file.csv')

df2 = keys.groupby('tag').apply(lambda x: x['keyword'].unique())
for keyword in df2.index:
    df[keyword] = ''
```

What my df2 looks like:

```
col Tag                                                            Keywords
access bypass                                                      [access bypass]
access control                   [access control, dma access control, trigger a...
already admin                               [have valid administrative privileges]
ansi escape                                                          [ansi escape]
application execution                                     [cause a service to run]
```

I tried something like this but got stuck very quick:

```
for keyword in df2.index:
    for tag in df2:
        for word in tag:
            for row in df:
                if word in df.iloc[]
```

**Here's an example of data**

```
col Name Description AccessControl AlreadyAdmin ArrayAccess .... xmlInjection xmlParsing
0   CVE1 Long Desc
1   CVE2 Long Desc
2   CVE3 Long Desc
3   CVE4 Long Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this would do:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['This contains Keyword 1', 'This contains Keyword 4',
                                   'This contains Keyword 4  and Keyword 6']})


pattern = '|'.join(keys.keyword)
(df.Description
   .str.extractall(f'({pattern})')[0]
   .map(keys.set_index('keyword')['tag'])
   .reset_index(name='col')
   .assign(value=1)
   .pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='col', values='value', fill_value=0)

)
```

output:

```
col      Tag 1  Tag 2  Tag 3
level_0                     
0            1      0      0
1            0      1      0
2            0      1      1
```

Comment: I apologize. I realize how I typed it was unclear. There are no actual '|', that was just my way of designating separate columns in the CSV file. I edited the question.

Comment: I understood that. the `|` in my code simply means `or` in regex pattern.

Comment: I see. I'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Can you provide the data? The code works on my example.

Comment: I added some data. I'm not sure what you need but I tried to provide as much context as possible. I would just attach my data files but I don't think you can do that right?

Comment: If it's not senstive, you could upload your csv to github/dropbox/etc... and share the link here.

Comment: Not sensitive. Here are the two data files and the code I have so far. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x44mpvq1svfujjz/AAAHqHIoDeKT_iRvGStPGetxa?dl=0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203781/discussion-between-cameron-kormylo-and-quang-hoang).

Comment: Were you able to access the data files?

Comment: I could, but did not have time to look at it yet.

Comment: That's okay. I figured out the answer. See below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kormy\Desktop\Webscraping\mitre_Data.csv')
keys = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kormy\Desktop\Webscraping\tags.csv')
df2 = keys.groupby('tag').apply(lambda x: x['keyword'].unique())
for keyword in df2.index:
    df[keyword] = ''

for col in df2.index:
    df[col] = pd.np.where(df.Description.str.contains('|'.join(df2[col])),1,0)
```